# Tensorflow dataset - map json

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to build a dataset with the dataset api, my situation is the following:

1. I have a set of json indicating for each instance a couple of images (in my case image and its mask)
2. I want to map every json and return the couple of images as tensors

In pure python I'd do something like

```
import json
import tensorflow as tf
def parse_json(json_path):
  json_file = json.load(open(json_path))
  img = tf.io.read_file(json_file['img'])
  mask = tf.io.read_file(json_file['mask']

  return img, mask
```

How can I achieve the same result with Tensorflow API? 
Thanks for your help!